# MongoDB/Mongoose: How can I count documents in one collection and add it to another based on id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello beautiful community. Hope you guys are doing okay.

So I'm working on this app where I have two MongoDB collections, `Posts` and `CommentsView`.

`Posts` collection consists of `post title`, `post type` and their `comments`. The `comments` is an array of objects that consists of how many times each comment is viewed and the id.

In the `CommentsView` collection, I intend to store all the comments when they are viewed. Duplicates is not a problem.

Here's how the schema looks like:

Posts Schema:

```
const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    postTitle: {
        type: String
    },
    comments: [ {
        totalViews: {
            type: Number
        },
        uid: {
            type: String
        }
    }],
    postId: {
        type: String
    }
} );
```

CommentsView Schema:

```
const commentsViewSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    text: {
        type: String,
    },
    uid: {
        type: String
    }
} );
```

Suppose I have a post with two comments with uid 'A' and 'B' respectively. Whenever the comment with uid 'A' is viewed, I will create a comment in `CommentsView` collection. And automatically add 1 view in `Posts` collection's `totalView` field. When the same comment is viewed again, I will first add it in `CommentsView` collection then increment `totalView` field in Posts collection.

Suppose I have these documents in Comments collection:

```
{
    text: 'Life is good',
    uid: 'A'
},
{
    text: 'Boom Boom',
    uid: 'B'
},
{
    text: 'Bam Bam',
    uid: 'A'
},
```

So the Posts document will look like this:

```
{
    postTile: '60 seconds to Mars',
    comments: [
        {
             uid: 'A',
             totalViews: 2,
        },
        {
             uid: 'B',
             totalViews: 1,
        },
    ],
    postId: '1s93njs'    
}
```

I have not tried anything yet as I have no idea where to start. It seems so complicated.

How can I achieve this if I want the whole process to be automatic?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using two different schema, I recommend you to use references,
beacause if you want to add more features like number of likes and threads then this model suggested below will be useful

**Don't** use **String** type for storing Id's of the model use the type **ObjectId** provided by the mongoose module.

**Post Model**

```
const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
postTitle: {
    type: String
},
comments: [ 
    type:ObjectId,
    ref:"model name"
],
    postId: {
      type: String
    }
}, {timestamps:true});
```

**Comment Model**

```
 const commentsViewSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
       text: {
         type: String,
         required:true
       },
       totalView:{
          type: Number,
          default:0
       }
  },{timestamps:true} );
```

now each time a post is viewed you can search for the commment id and increment the count in the document. and everything will be reflected in the post model if you populate all the comments in the array

**Example**

**work flow**

**User Viewed the comment-->(getcomment_id) -->  update the comment**

Now all **subsequent request** for the post with this comment will also have the updated view because of reference.

**query to update the comments**

**comment.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:<comment_id>}, {$inc:{totalView:1}})**

other way is to have embedded do, I recommend this if you think there won't be much comments for the posts, otherwise having the above model is good.

you can further refer to these articles

[rules to follow for designing mongodb schema](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1)

Hope this helped you get a good idea

Comment: Hey man. Thanks for the answer. But sadly that is not what I wanted. Let me explain it to you again. The posts model creates a post and whenever there is a comment made by a user it will be added in comments array as an object. I have not mentioned Comments model in the OP because Comments model is separate than CommentsView model.

Comment: CommentsView model will only create documents whenever a comment is viewed. 1 comment can be viewed by a million people. And I need to store those million people's IP as well. So duplicate is not an issue. I just need to count those 1 million documents in CommentsView  and store this amount in Posts' comments array by finding it by the id.